# Nullpointerexception arraylistfunction

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make this simple function:

```
private void getID(){
    for(int i=0;i<crops.size();i++){
        ID.add(i);
    }
}
```

where `cropps.size()` is the size of a bitmaparraylist which i've made. People told me that these function fail because you can get the argument null. But how can i get null if i don't fill in any arguments...

I've also tried to make the input of the function an `Arraylist` of integers but this failed as wel. On my `Oncreate` method i use `getID()` after i made the crops so that isn't the error as well. So i'm kind of confused here and help would be much appreciated.

Kees

Comment: If you get a NPE, `crops` or `ID` can be null. Without seeing if you initialize them well we can't tell you what's causing the failure.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @ZouZou, my ID list is an empty arraylist but that doen't mean its null right?

Comment: No if you initialize it well, it shoudln't be null. However, crops can be null. Follow the stacktrace, see at which line this error is coming, this will tell you what is null.

Comment: @ZouZou, thanks :), it says it gets the error in the line where 

ID.add(i);

occurs

So ID should be null, but i defined ID as:

ArrayList<Integer> ID;

Is the problem maybe that i should change that in:

ArrayList<Integer> ID = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: Yes  `ArrayList<Integer> ID` declares ID as an ArrayList of Integer, but it doesn't mean that it's initialized. declaration != initialization !!!